# Sorting a collection of numbers

Tags: uml, ocl

[Link to OCL documentation](http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.4/PDF)

If I have a collection of Cars, I can sort it by engine power like this:

```
collectionOfCars -> sortedBy(car|car.power)
```

or simply

```
 collectionOfCars -> sortedBy(power)
```

How to sort a collection of numbers? Are the following expressions correct?

```
collectionOfNumbers -> sortedBy(a|a)

collectionOfNumbers -> sortedBy()
```

Comment: Depends on how your numbers are specified (i.e. which type/class do they have).

Comment: Let's say it's a collection of integers, or reals.

Comment: They are just pure numbers, not object of some class. That's the problem, I have no attribute to refer to in sortedBy. But I don't think I can't sort a collection of integers in OCL.

Comment: A collection can only contain objects. And Integers are no objects. You are dealing with C-structures.

Comment: OK, let it be a collection of Integers (Set of object of class Integer). It's one of UML primitive types I believe.

Comment: There are no such things like what you call UML primitives.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally have collection of integers in OCL (as well as collection of String and all OCL "primitive types"), they are called collections of literals (p.25 on OCL specification). You can build them from scratch using `{}`, e.g. `Sequence{3,2,4,1}`.

Also, consider this `c.ownedAttribute.name` (where `c` is a class), you will build a collection of String (this expression use the implicit iterator `.`)

If you want to sort your collection of literal, you can do `collection->sortedBy(a|a)` as proposed.

`Sequence{3,2,4,1}->sortedBy(a|a)` result `Sequence{1,2,3,4} : Seqence(Integer)`

`Bag{8,7,8,9}->sortedBy(i|i)` result `Sequence{7,8,8,9} : Sequence(Integer)`

You can find more examples in this paper "Object Constraint Language (OCL):
A Definitive Guide" by Jordi Cabot and Martin Gogolla, you can find the paper here:
http://www.db.informatik.uni-bremen.de/publications/Cabot_2012_SFM.pdf